# Compatibility between JOOQ and spring-boot version

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

spring-boot 3.0.12 uses JOOQ 3.17.16 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/6e967bcb5e8f760126142bea2d9360c7b0dc5574/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L663).

Can someone let me know if JOOQ 3.18.x compatible with spring-boot 3.0.12? What is the general compatibility guideline between JOOQ and spring-boot versions?